# Book about a girl whose hair changes with the seasons

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I read this book probably early 2000's but it would of been published in the 90s. (I think)

In the story it's a girl who has to go journey somewhere (I don't really remember the main bits of the book) and her hair literally changes every time the seasons change... So in autumn her hair is like rust reds and browns etc. But food also grows in her hair? Like for autumn acorns and apples and whatnot and then in summer her hair is golden blonde and she has wheat growing... In spring I think her hair has flowers growing?

Does anyone know this story?

Answer (score 6):

Could this be "[Maximum Ride](http://www.goodreads.com/series/43579-maximum-ride)" by James Patterson?

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Ride) for the book series mentions that the protagonist's hair changes colour with the seasons;

> Maximum "Max" Ride is the title character and the primary protagonist
>   of the series. She is a 14 year-old (15 in Fang, Angel, and Nevermore)
>   avian-human hybrid and the leader of the Flock. She has brown hair
>   that was originally brownish red but became sun bleached, peachy skin
>   and brown eyes, but is described differently in the manga, where she
>   has completely blonde hair. Some fans have hypothesized that the
>   change in Max's hair color might be because Angel and Gazzy already
>   have blonde hair, yet only Nudge has brown hair.[citation needed]
>   However, **it is mentioned throughout the series that her hair changes
>   color according to season**

Comment: No, I've read Maximum ride. The book I'm talking about her hair literally also grows things like wheat and acorns, etc. It's more magic than bird hybrids.

Comment: Does her hair really change? I thought her hair colour is actually inconsistent

Answer (score 3):

[*Treasure at the Heart of the Tanglewood*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/691995.Treasure_at_the_Heart_of_the_Tanglewood) by Meredith Ann Pierce.  published 2001.

[image: Book cover]

The main character is a girl, a healer, whose hair grows the bounty of nature - herbs and flowers, vines, shoots and so on.  She harvests it to make a healing potion for the local poor, or a magic elixir for her guardian/keeper, at first.  Over the course of the book, she leaves her keeper to find her past and answers, and as she goes she changes both hair color and name from Brown Hannah (winter, but also untapped potential) to Green of spring, Golden with summer, and Russet Hannah in autumn as the magic moves with the seasons and her own growth.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find it as well. She has shoots and what it in her hair. It's *Treasure at the Heart of Tangle Woods*.

Comment: Sorry, this is a low quality answer.